# Inconsistent "incorrect format" error

Tags: .net

.NET Framework 4.0
Windows 2012

I have two EXE's that use a single DLL.  One of the EXE's always works, but the other EXE always fails with this message:

> Could not load file or assembly '{dllHere}, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Each EXE is in a separate folder and each folder contains its own identical copy of the DLL.  A Google search points to this being caused by compiling the DLL for the wrong CPU.  Since it works for one EXE, I don't see that being the problem.

Both EXE's run fine on my Win7 PC and a Win2003 server.

What causes this error?

Comment: How are the executables compiled? If they are "CPU any" then the same exe will work on either 32 or 64 bit. Check that the dll is also compiled "CPU any".

Comment: Maybe you should check superuser for this, as it is not a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both projects (.EXE's) use the same platform target, e.g compile them both either on x86 or x64, depending on the library's target platform.

Comment: The failing EXE and the DLL both have "Target CPU: x86".  On my Win7 PC, the process shows the *32 suffix.  On the Win2012 server, it doesn't have that suffix.

Answer (score 0):

.NET allows AnyCPU as a target. This means that the same executable can run as both 32-bit and 64-bit executable. This can easily cause your scenario - one of your applications is compiled as AnyCPU, the other as 32-bit. If the DLL is 32-bit, only the 32-bit application will work. If the DLL is 64-bit, only the AnyCPU application will work. Since this works on other computers, the best bet is that the DLL is 32-bit, and your Win7 and Win2k3 PCs are 32-bit, so both applications run as 32-bit.

You can check if a process is running as 32-bit or 64-bit in the task manager - 32-bit processes have a `*32` postfix.